# Input hidden + select

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho um foreach que vai populando o select conforme abaixo:

```
<select id="status" name="status[]" class="order-type">
     <?php foreach ($produtos as $produto) : ?>
        <option value="$produto['id']"><?=$produto['nome'];?></option>
     <?php
           endforeach
     ?>
</select>
```

Quero passar também o preço do produto pois preciso exibi-lo na tabela conforme imagem abaixo, tentei fazer com input hidden, dessa forma:

```
<select id="status" name="status[]" class="order-type">
     <?php foreach ($produtos as $produto) : ?>
        <option value="$produto['id']"><?=$produto['nome'];?></option>
        <input type="hidden" name="preco" value="<?=$produto['preco']?>">
     <?php
           endforeach
     ?>
</select>
```

Mas dai os próximos produtos ficam fora do select, conforme abaixo:

[image: Erro no select após inserir input hidden]

Esses dados eu recebo no javaScript dessa forma:

```
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){
    var form_data = {};
    var dados = {};
    form_data["status"] = $('.payment-form #status option:selected').text();
    form_data["amount"] = $('.payment-form input[name="amount[]"]').val();
    form_data["valor"]  = $('.payment-form input[name="valor"]').val();
    var valor  = getMoney($('.payment-form input[name="valor"]').val());
    form_data["total"] = formatReal(("R$ "+form_data["amount"] * valor));
    var total = form_data["amount"] * valor;
    form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="ico-cancel"></span>';
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');

    $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
      $('<td class="input-'+type+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
    });
    $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[]").val(form_data["status"]).appendTo(row);
    $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[]").val(form_data["amount"]).appendTo(row);
    // $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto"+ contador + "[]").val(form_data["valor"]).appendTo(row);
    contador++;
    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row);
     sum += total;
    $(".preview-total").text(formatReal(sum));
});
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar a resolver? Ou alguma outra maneira de passar o preco?

Obrigado.

Comment: Esse select é multiplo?

Comment: Não, é simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é o `input` dentro do `select`. Dentro do `select`, apenas tags `option` podem estar contidas.

Não sei qual o domínio da sua aplicação, mas não recomendo passar um preço através de um `input` do lado do cliente para a aplicação por razões de segurança: imagine em um e-commerce se um usuário resolve editar este preço e fazer o checkout do carrinho de compras? O preço errado seria utilizado, e o usuário beneficiado.

Se realmente deseja ter o preço do lado do cliente, recomendo que adicione um atributo à tag `option`, informando o preço:

```
<option value="$produto['id']" preco="$produto['preco']"><?=$produto['nome'];?></option>
```

Neste caso, será necessário um pouco de Javascript, dependendo do seu uso.

**Edição**

Utilizando a sugestão acima para passar o preço como um atributo da tag `option`, pode-se utilizar o seguinte comando para pegar o preço associado a opção selecionada na combo:

```
$('.payment-form #status option:selected').attr('preco');
```

No JS da pergunta, não vi nenhuma referência ao `input` previamente adicionado, mas acredito que seja referente aos locais onde utiliza o selector `.payment-form input[name="valor"]`.

Neste caso, por exemplo, a linha:

```
form_data["valor"]  = $('.payment-form input[name="valor"]').val();
```

se torna:

```
form_data["valor"]  = $('.payment-form #status option:selected').attr('preco');
```

O mesmo processo deve ser utilizado nas demais ocorrências aonde deseja pegar o preço do produto selecionado.

Comment: Verdade Vinícius, não tinha me tocado disso hehe..como você me aconselha a enviar o preco?

Comment: @user13840 sinceramente recomendo não enviar, pois dependendo do domínio da sua aplicação, não há implicações sérias de segurança. Edite na sua pergunta como você esta fazendo o envio hoje destas informações (se utiliza `form`, se é Ajax, se utiliza jQuery, etc), para que eu possa dar uma resposta mais direcionada =]

Comment: Vinícius, veja se consegue me ajudar agora por favor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, veja se ficou claro agora.

Comment: Shooowwww, já marquei como resposta, muito Obrigado Vinícius.